# How to make texture not repeat

Tags: texturing, uv, transparency, error, vertex-groups

I've imported a face and shirt texture for a model but the shirt texture is repeating and overlapping the face texture where it is not specified to exist which creates this monstrosity.[image]

I've got both materials in the editor

[image]

and the image is set to clip but it's still overlapping

[image]

You're a literal legend if you help me by the way.

Edit: This might not be a problem with repeating and more a problem with the wrong vertex groups being assigned to the shirt texture, there's a model with the correct textures in the blend file if it helps.
Here's the blend file link
[image]

Comment: Working on it… first off, the wrong material was assigned to the head. (Not called vertex groups in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple problems with the mesh, but it all came down to materials being assigned to the wrong places. The shirt material was assigned to the head, mouth, and eyes. Create new material slots for these areas, select the already working-on-other-character materials from the list of options for each slot rather than creating new ones, and assign them to the right places. Since several duplicate vertices exist, I personally recommend selecting all and merging by distance first, then using Select Linked but limited to UV to easily select one-material areas.

For more information, see [the Blender Manual on Material Assignment](http://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/assignment.html)